# Eliminar columna de índice en DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

No logro eliminar una columna que se me genera al guardar un df a un archivo xlsx. Lo curioso es que si guardo el mismo df en un archivo csv, esta columna de índices no aparece,

Copio mi script completo, tal vez estoy haciendo algo más y agregándola sin darme cuenta.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from datetime import datetime
import re
from pathlib import Path
import os
import pandas as pd

hora = datetime.now()
dia = hora.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
fecha = hora.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S")
ruta = Path("E:\Python\Visual Studio Code Proyects\M2M Real\Archivos\Router - show interfaces description pipe include Gi0-3-4-3.txt")
ruta2 = Path("E:\Python\Visual Studio Code Proyects\M2M Real\Archivos\\")

with open(ruta, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open(ruta, "w") as fw:
    for line in lines:
        if not re.match("-{5}|\s+|([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)", line):
            fw.write(line)

csv_name2 = f'{ruta2}\{ruta.stem}.csv'
csv_name3 = f'{ruta2}\{ruta.stem}.xlsx'

df = pd.read_fwf(ruta)

df["Description"] = (df.iloc[:, 3:].fillna("").astype(str).apply(" ".join, axis=1).str.strip())

df = df.iloc[:, :4]

df = df.drop(columns = ["Status", "Protocol"])

df.Interface = df.Interface.str.extract('Gi0/3/4/3\.(\d+)')

df = df[df.Interface.notnull()].reset_index()

df = df.drop(columns = ["index"])

df['Interface'] = df['Interface'].astype(int)

df = df.set_index('Interface').reindex(range(1,3580)).fillna('free').reset_index()

df1 = df.to_csv(csv_name2, index=False, sep=";")

df = df.to_excel(csv_name3, sheet_name='FRUVE01 - Gi0-3-4-3')
```

txt inicial:

```
Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
Gi0/3/4/3          up          up          ENLACE A Router B
Gi0/3/4/3.401      up          up          Frontera Cliente A
Gi0/3/4/3.402      up          up          Frontera Cliente B
Gi0/3/4/3.403      up          up          Frontera Cliente C
Gi0/3/4/3.404      up          up          Frontera Cliente D
etc...
```

Así se ve el archivo como csv:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y así como xlsx:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté utilizar el método `drop` en sus diferentes variables ya sea por ubicación numérica o comillas sin contenido, como asumiendo que no tiene nombre, pero me da error o no hace nada:

```
df = df.drop([""], axis=1)
df = df.drop([[0]], axis=1)
```

¿Alguna solución para borrar esa columna de índices que no necesito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes pasar el parámetro `index` en `False` a la función [`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

```
df.to_excel(csv_name3, sheet_name='FRUVE01 - Gi0-3-4-3', index=False)
```

Comment: (icono facepalm) no te la puedo believe!!! yo tenia entendido q servia para otra cosa ese parametro, una vez mas muchas gracias GmrYael!!